# Is it possible to view the "read status" of a message in Slack?

Tags: slack

Sometimes I want to know if a specific person has seen a message yet without having to Direct Message them.  Is it possible to see read-status in Slack? How?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no read receipt feature, although it is on their dev backlog according to this [Tweet thread](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/504407968150851585).

There isn't much you can do outside of asking if they saw it. Some other possibilities:

1. Look at their screen to see if their Slack app is showing the unread message notification. This isn't perfect though. You'll know they read it if the notification isn't there, but they may have also seen it even with the notification showing, due to other unread messages.
2. If they are offline when you message them, wait around to see if they appear online shortly after you send the message. That is a likely indication that they read it. Having said that, it might be possible that a user's account is "sleeping" and the act of receiving the message sets them as online. You can test this with someone that has the Slack app on their phone. Have them login and leave the app alone for some time. Once they no longer appear online, send them a message and see of they come online without having to reopen the app.

Comment: You can also ask people to add reaction to your important post when they have read it. Quickly from the message line. e.g.: `+:rocket: `

Comment: The Tweet thread is more than 2 years old and they still didn't implement this feature. Wonder which is the priority of this in their backlog.

Comment: Um.... 2 more years has passed, and it seems it is still not implemented.

Comment: Um.... 2 more years have passed, and it seems it is still not implemented @cytsunny

Comment: Slack is so much better without the `message is read` functionality IMO.

Comment: Another alternative is to send message through MS Teams or Messenger :D

Comment: Um.... 2 more years have passed, and it seems it is still not implemented @ShukantPal

Comment: 2 More years passed... still nothing ! @Mikant

Comment: Read receipts encourage micromanagement. Slack is better off without read receipts.

Comment: I was hoping for that feature because some messages are more urgent than others and I was looking for a workflow that would have a receipt that someone actually read it and didn't gloss over it. People can mistakenly mark messages as read accidentally. I think an alternative to read receipts is to CC people in a given message who I want to be sure read something. Still no guarantee but it improves the odds I guess.