# Is there a way to know how many people viewed a particular message?

Tags: slack

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to know how many workspace members have viewed a particular message in Slack?

Comment: Probably not. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94962/is-it-possible-to-view-the-read-status-of-a-message-in-slack or https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/6ubh7f/slack_read_receipts_are_finally_here/

Answer (score 1):

No. To the best of my knowledge Slack does not store the number of views of a message.

Even if you pull the internal information about a message from the API (e.g. with [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history)) this does not include any views information.